# Settings entry without settings bundle IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, settings.bundle

Is there any steps to create settings entry **without settings bundle**.

When I searched how to add my app to settings app in ios, i found that we need to add settings bundle. I also found some project that get added to settings app without settings bundle. how it is done?

If we register for push or VOIP notification, do the settings entry automatically get created?

Thank you,

Comment: not getting your question properly!

Comment: @Lion, I edited the question. I hope you can understand it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your app automatically will display in setting app for different permission like `camara,photolibrary,location,microphone` etc. Whatever functionality you will used your app add that category in setting app.

So, if you implement `VOIP or push notification`(for example successfully register for notification) then setting app will show settings about that also.